# My custom templates for 404 page not working in Django

Tags: python, html, django, http, http-status-code-404

I've been trying to use my custom 404- and 403 pages for my django project and I used code for it that I already used in other projects, but somehow it's not working yet.

This is my function:

```
def error_404(request, exception):
    return render(request, 'main/errors/404.html', status=404)
```

And this is where i call the function in the `urls.py`:

```
handler404 = 'main_app.views.error_404'
```

This is my 404.html:

```
{% extends "../base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load i18n %}
<html>

<header>
    {% block title %}<h1>404 - {% trans "Page not found" %}</h1>{% endblock %}
</header>
<main>
    {% block content %}
    <p>The page your looking for could not be found</p>
    {% endblock %}
</main>


</html>
```

The pathes should actually be fine, since I used `render(template_name=)` alot in this project and I just copied it and changed the file name. I also set the `DEBUG=False` in the `settings.py`

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, and this is the approach I always used, the way to do it is to simply create a `404.html` page at root level in the templates folder.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had some errors in the template anyway but this solved my problem, I have my custom templates now :)